# JavaScript/HTML in browser on Mac

Tags: javascript, html, macos, character-encoding

I'm starting out with Javascript coding on a mac but am having problems. I'm using very basic script embedded within HTML pages using text edit. I've tried exactly the same code with my windows pc and it works fine but whenever I try on the Mac it is glitchy (eg all quotation marks for strings are replaced with characters like `â€¨ â€¨ â€¨`) and doesn't work properly in the browser. Anyone else encountered this on a MacBook and, if so, how did you manage to fix it?

Comment: sounds like a browser encoding problem rather a js/html one

Comment: Thanks - I did wonder that but exact same text works on Chrome on the windows PC so I think it's probably something to do with the Mac

Answer (score 0):

your encoding sounds like it might be different/incorrect. you might have "magic" quotes if you're using text edit. I would recommend using a different text editor like sublime text or textmate as they don't encode your quotes differently.

Comment: I did copy and paste from textedit to sublime and same issue was persisting - will try retyping from scratch in sublime to see if that helps. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You Need to set the charset to UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks, the Mac is showing as being UTF-8 but it's still happening - will have another crack using Sublime to see if that works. Cheers